# How to use "alter system.." sql statement in AWS RDS oracle?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, privileges

```
"ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE;"
```

to delete data buffer cache of oracle db command was used.

But then the error occurred.
SQL Error [1031] [42000]: ORA-01031

So I used another command:

```
"EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.flush_buffer_cache;
```

The following error occurred.
SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900

According to the documentation, "exec admin.admin_util.flush_buffer_cache;" This command says it can be used, but can you tell me why it can't?

And is there any other way to do flust_buffer_cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error indicates that your user doesn't have privileges to use `alter system`.

The second error indicates your command is incorrect. You seem to have lost the "rds" from "rdsadmin". Have you tried this:

```
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.flush_buffer_cache;
```

or

```
begin
    rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.flush_buffer_cache;
end;
/
```

Per the AWS documentation, here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.System.html

Comment: "EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.flush_buffer_cache; "I ran it with this command, but I posted it wrong.

Comment: try putting it in an anonymous PL/SQL block; i edited my answer to include one. Are there any other errors shown? It could be that you don't have privileges to execute that procedure either. What make you feel that you need to flush the cache? It generally isn't necessary unless you're dealing with some specific data corruption issues.

Comment: I tried using the pl/sql block but I get the same error. As you know, the official documentation says that the sql statement is executed, but I'm curious because it doesn't work.

Comment: It feels like this is a permissions issue - that the account you're using doesn't have the correct privileges, or something like that. Still curious why you're attempting to do this: in most cases clearing the buffer cache will have a serious negative affect on performance.